# How run a function only for Colliders in a the radius?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to run a function *{deadScript.Destroy()}*, but only for those Colliders who are in the radius, but i don't know how.
I want the players who are in the radius to disappear, this is already set in the dead.Script.Destroy()

The Code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BombExpl : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject BombPrefab;
public float time;
public LayerMask DestroyableObjectLayer;
public float Radius;
public GameObject ExplosionVisual;


Shake functionScript;
//DestroyScript deadScript;




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Invoke("Explosion", time);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Explosion()
    {
        
        Collider2D[] objects = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, Radius, DestroyableObjectLayer);
        foreach (Collider2D obj in objects)
        {
        Instantiate(ExplosionVisual,transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(obj.gameObject);
        functionScript = FindObjectOfType<Shake>();
        functionScript.Boom();
        SoundManagerScript.PlaySound ("expl");
        
        //deadScript = FindObjectOfType<DestroyScript>();
        //deadScript.Destroy();
        
        
        }
    }
    
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(this.transform.position, Radius);
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, _"Unity Script"_, the JS-like language is no longer a thing.  It's just `c#` now which is what your question should be tagged.  I have done this for you.  Good luck!

Comment: So in the foreach loop you need to calculate the distance between the `obj.transform.position` and `this.transform.position` and only explode if it's within a certain radius. I haven't worked with unity3d, but it might give an idea how to solve it

Comment: Well you got the destroyableobjextlayer. Why not do the same for players

Comment: So what is the issue/question? As I can tell you already make an `OverlapCircleAll` with a certain `Radius` so it will only return the colliders within that radius ... If you want a second inner radius .. well then add one and compare `Vector3.Distance(obj.transform.position, transform.position) <= innerRadius`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I forgot to mention That ist is in 2d

Answer (score 0):

Use CollidercircleNonAlloc to check frequently and not store garbage.

```
Collider2D[] hitsBuf = new Collider2D[30]; //limit the amount of possible hits

void FixedUpdate()
{
    int numHits = Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc(Position, Radius, hitsBuf , DestroyableObjectLayer.value);
    Explosion(hitsBuf ,numHits);
}

public void Explosion(Collider2D[] hitsBuf , int numHits)
{

for(int i = 0; i < numHits; i++)
{
    Instantiate(ExplosionVisual,transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Destroy(obj.gameObject);
    functionScript = FindObjectOfType<Shake>();
    functionScript.Boom();
    SoundManagerScript.PlaySound ("expl");
}
}
```

Comment: That's a nice **comment** for using an alternative method ... but besides the allocation and eventually not returning all objects anymore this doesn't really change anything else ...